# What is wrong with this "edit count" query on the SE data explorer?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I've been trying to come up with a query which will tell me how may edits someone has done as per the rules for the **Strunk & White** and **Copy Editor** badges.

So far I've come up with this:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/843/user-edit-count

I know that it has a number of potential problems with counting edits that it shouldn't do, including:

- If an edit is made to the title and body of a post at the same time I suspect 2 edits might be counted instead of 1
- Edits made to CW questions are counted
- It counts multiple edits to the same question

But it is still reporting a edit count that is too low - for user Id 114029 (who according to the data dump has the Strunk & White badge), this query reports only 71 edits.

What have I missed?  Why is the edit count returned too low?

Comment: It's too low because of the data dump cutoff, but the query itself will report too high because of the anomalies you mentioned. (Multiple edits on the same post don't count?)

Answer (score 2):

Use either of these instead which are more accurate

- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/692/check-strunk-und-white-process-for-current-user
- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/511/progress-towards-editor-badges

They don't agree, but both show the user over the threshold

FYI - The data dump is updated only once every month.  It is nearly 3 weeks old by now https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

Comment: Read the question - it is from the same data dump that the user id was obtained, so the answer here is irrelevant

Comment: Both of those queries use the Posts table and so are pretty much guaranteed to be incorrect - since they were written the PostHistory table has been added which should contain the information needed to accurately work out the number of edits.

Comment: While that is true, those are the ready queries you can use with a slight margin of error. Given the dump is X days old, that margin of error is less than the rate of change except for the most avid SO users