# Strunk-and-White problem?

Tags: support, data-explorer, edit-badges

Thanks to the new edit system(which I really like, BTW) I recently got Strunk-and-White.  Awesome!  I'm a curious guy, so I had been periodically seeing how many edits I had with [some](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/5117/how-many-edits-until-strunk-white) [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/5157/how-many-edits-have-I-made?UserId=40468) [queries.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/87932/select-top-1000-id-as-user-link-select-count-from-pos)  I was about 35-40 away last time I checked, so I went back and...

- [Query 1](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/5117/how-many-edits-until-strunk-white) says I still need 32 edits for S&W
- [Query 2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/5157/how-many-edits-have-I-made?UserId=40468) says I only have 68 edits
- [Query 3](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/87932/select-top-1000-id-as-user-link-select-count-from-pos) says I only have 69 edits

Are these queries all flawed? Is there a bug in the S&W badge? Is there another explanation?

Comment: I've been wondering the [same thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76324/what-is-wrong-with-this-edit-count-query-on-the-se-data-explorer).

Comment: Check this out - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/copy-editor-with-too-few-revisions

Comment: The requirements for the badge changed yesterday.  So all of the queries may be wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe these are based on monthly data dumps not real time queries. From the FAQ section:-

```
How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?

Data is updated monthly.
```

Comment: -facepalm-  That's what I get for posted on little sleep.

Comment: Data *are* updated monthly. Speaking of Strunk & White problems..

Comment: @Scott S: "Data is" is perfectly grammatical. I humbly direct you to these questions over at English Language and Usage for details: [Data is or data are?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6904/) and [Where are the “data”? I only have one “datum”.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/)

Answer (score 9):

There are two problems:

1. As [CoolBeans noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80166/strunk-and-white-problem/80167#80167), the data dumps are behind.
2. In addition, the queries are flawed as they only consider the most recent editor, even though the badges [consider all editors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57735/do-you-have-to-be-the-last-editor-for-it-to-count-against-the-editing-badges). It is now possible to construct a query which considers all editors (which could not be done at the time), but it appears no one has done so yet.

Answer (score 8):

#### Update:

I wrote a final query to determine how many edits you've made and how much more until you earn the badges.  This is based on the query waffles had graciously shared with us in the comments below.  It should be accurate now though still behind as expected due to to it using the monthly dumps.  This will be the final version from me (aside from any performance tweaks).

[How many edits have I made and how much more until I earn the badges?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1024/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges)

---

#### Older queries:

Based on the older way of counting edits.
[How many edits have I made and how much more until I earn the badges? (v1)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1009/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges-v1)

Based on waffles' description [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/copy-editor-with-too-few-revisions/80260#80260) counting posts that are edited.
[How many edits have I made and how much more until I earn the badges? (v2)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1016/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges-v2)

Based on v2 but counts revisions instead of posts.  It is ultimately the final version so I have deleted it.  I'm leaving the link here for historical purposes.
[How many edits have I made and how much more until I earn the badges? (v3)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1023/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges-v3)

Comment: 97.  Yep, that sounds a bit more accurate.  +1.

Comment: @John: I've added an alternative query based on the new explanation that you linked to.  Looks like we're being cut down a bit more now.

Comment: That one says I need 7 more to S&W, but with the whole monthly update thing it's probably right.

Comment: you need to account for post history type, PostHistoryTypeId in (4,5) .... also be sure to exclude self edits

Comment: @waffles: That's taken care of in the second version.  ;)

Comment: @waffles: Are there any other ways I can make these queries more accurate?  Right now I only count posts/revisions that are non-self edits that modifies the title or body that isn't deleted.  Are tag wiki edits included?  Are CW edits excluded?  Is it counting the posts or the revisions?  Would be really helpful if you could answer these.

Comment: @Jeff .. tag wikis and CW are included ... here is our current query ... 
  select max(UserId) as UserId from PostHistory ph where PostHistoryTypeId in (4,5) and 
  PostId not in
   (
    select p.Id from Posts p where p.OwnerUserId = ph.UserId or DeletionDate is not null 
   )
  group by UserId having COUNT(distinct RevisionGUID) >= 500

Comment: @John: Final version added.  Now ought to be the most accurate.

Answer (score 6):

[CoolBeans'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80166/strunk-and-white-problem/80167#80167) and [waiwai933's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80166/strunk-and-white-problem/80172#80172) answers still only explain part of it.

I'll add (3): the Strunk & White badge has recently (yesterday?) been changed from needing 100 edits to needing only 80.

Comment: And Copy Editor needs 500 (instead of 600)

Comment: Oh, wow, I had no idea...do you have a source for this?

Comment: @John The [Badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) page on any site. I can't find any other source. But I had been checking my progress too and was surprised to get the badge today.

Comment: @Jeff, @Mercator: [Found it :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/79054/copy-editor-with-too-few-revisions/80260#80260)

Answer (score 1):

And just to throw another query into the mix...

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1026/editor-strunk-white-copy-editor