# What happened to my Copy Editor badge?

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

A few days ago I had the gold Copy Editor badge on Stack Overflow for 500 edits. Today I don't. I checked the Data Explorer and according to that I have only made 100 edits. I didn't think badges would be revoked once earned, and even if they are I don't see how 400 edits can disappear so quickly.

What has happened?

Comment: Which SEDE query did you use? Many of them are flawed, because they only track a post's most recent editor. When I earned Copy Editor (back when it was for 600 edits), the query said I was still ~440 edits short.

Comment: I used a flawed one apparently. I tried the one Jeff M posted and got 244 edits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/copy-editor-with-too-few-revisions/80260#80260), the logic for getting the editing badges have changed.  I guess the badges are being revoked and re-rewarded based on this logic.  His comment below on that answer seems to confirm that.

I've [written a new query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80166/strunk-and-white-problem/80405#80405) that takes this into account.

Comment: Does that query take into account Tag Wiki edits? Assuming that Tag Wiki edits count towards the badge of course...

Comment: Thanks. New query says 244 edits, half way there! :)

Answer (score 4):

The edits didn't disappear.

- The data explorer data is up to a month out of date so your edits for February won't count.
- The queries on the data explorer tend to under-report edits as they only identify those posts where **you were the last editor**. If someone else edits the same post later, the fact that you edited the post is "forgotten".
- The rules on multiple edits to the same post were tightened. You now have to make edits to 500 posts (which isn't quite the same). [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/copy-editor-with-too-few-revisions/80260#80260)

So you probably lost the badge due to the last change, but you are closer than you think because of the 1<sup>st</sup> two reasons.