# Strunk & White badge and data explorer question

Tags: support, badges, data-explorer, edit-badges

I've been fiddling with data-explorer recently, and I was curious to see how many edits I still need to earn the Strunk & White badge.

So I ran [how many edits I made and how much more until I earn the badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1024/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges) and I was a bit disappointed at the results:

> Damien Pirsy 4 0 76 496

So basically I'm supposed to have done only 4 regular edits, but I'm damn sure I did A LOT more...
I must point out that [I know the rules behind this badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258), which are the regular and which aren't, and still I think I've done much more than 4 *regular* edits.

I then bumped into this question: [Strunk & White problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80166/strunk-and-white-problem), I tried all the solutions and still obtained the same result; i'm talking specifically about this query: [User Edit Count.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/843/user-edit-count)

I read tens of similar questions here on meta: some were old (before the changes done to this badge), the others pointed me to the queries I run. I aknowledge that datas are taken from a monthly data dump, but still the count doesn't match...I don't think I have done so much edits just in the last month...I did more than before, but still...

Where am I doing wrong? By chance, do subsequent edits on a question/answer INVALIDATE my previous edits, and so do not count (for me) towards this achievement?

Can someone shed a light on this?

I forgot: I refer to my stackoverflow account Damien Pirsy, userid: 594509

Comment: Note that it's updated every _two_ months now.  Last update shows June 6th.

Comment: Ok, so from the August 6th on I would get the more accurate count, right?

Answer (score 5):

The data there is only updated every other month, so if you've been on a recent editing binge it may take a while to be reflected there. Also edits to your own posts don't count, nor do edits that only affect tags.

---

Actually I see from your [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594509/damien-pirsy?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_revisions) that you have done more than that, long enough ago that they should show up. I suspect that the query, being user-created, is just faulty. [This one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/409/how-many-edits-do-i-have) seems more accurate (though still not perfect, it can only count the *last* person who edited).

If you want to do more editing to earn some badges, you can help us in our [quest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97958/help-me-defeat-the-barbarians-in-the-regex-tag) to clean up [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Comment: Yeah, I ran that query and gives me 18. Maybe I am still far from the 80, I know, but they _have_ to be more...I know which edit counts and which not, I'm aware of that. I read of your quest, I even corrected the 'javascript' tag in some, I'll keep on ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this method is reliable because it fluctuates a lot but, if you want to see the number of edit a user made, you can do the folowing:

1. [Go to the users page and select editors and all](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all)
2. Enter the username in the  search box.
3. You now can see the number of edits.

According to that view, you have 44 edits.

Comment: This includes edits to your own posts, so is only a very rough guide to how close you are to the Strunk & White or Copy Editor badges.